# How do I find the gradient of a noise value which has been re-evaluated on a curve

Tags: mathematics, normal-mapping, curves, simplex-noise

I have a function `Evaluate()`, which is used to remap a noise value based on a curve/spline to make the noise more interesting. There are 3 inputs: the noise value to be remapped, the gradient of the noise, and the curve/spline. What I need help with is finding the new gradient.

```
// "noise" is in the range [0,1], and is the value form a noise function,
// "gradient" is the gradient of the noise function, 
// and "filter" has the heights of an animation curve in the interval [0,1]
private void Evaluate(ref float noise, ref float3 gradient, in UnsafeList<float> filter)
{
    int index = (int)(noise * (filter.Length - 1));
    
    float remap = filter[index]; // f(x)
    int h = index + 1 == filterResolution ? -1 : 1; // direction to evaluate the array
    float remaph = filter[index + h]; // f(x+h)
    gradient = (remaph - remap) / h * gradient; // curve derivative * noise derivative 
    noise = remap;
}
```

Comment: This is just the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). To calculate it you'd need the derivative of your animation curve as another array, or partial differences computed from adjacent indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain rule says

$$\frac {d} {d x}f(g(x)) = f^\prime(g(x)) \cdot g^\prime(x) $$

In your case you have three functions to compose:

- Your filter function \$f(i)\$ that you approximate stepwise 
  (You may get better results if you use a piecewise linear or spline interpolation here, to avoid stairstep artifacts from the truncation. Below, we'll pretend it's a smooth function so the flat steps don't zero-out the gradient)
- Your range remapping function \$r(i) = (\text{filter length} - 1)i\$
- Your noise function \$n(x, y, z)\$

So we need to multiply three coefficients here:

$$\frac {\delta} {\delta x}f(r(n(x,y,z))) = f^\prime(r(n(x,y,z))) \cdot r^\prime(n(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac {\delta n(x,y,z)} {\delta x}$$

In code that could look like this:

```cs
private void Evaluate(ref float noise, ref float3 gradient, in UnsafeList<float> filter)
{
    int index = (int)(noise * (filter.Length - 1));

    float filtered = filter[index];

    int maxIndex = Mathf.Min(index + 1, filter.Length - 1);
    int minIndex = Mathf.Max(index - 1, 0);

    float approximateSlope = (filter[maxIndex] - filter[minIndex]) 
                             / (maxIndex - minIndex);

    //               f'                   r'                n'
    gradient = approximateSlope * (filter.Length - 1) * gradient;
    noise = filtered;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly!